# autocomplete with multiselect outside div

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, multi-select

I am trying to do something  autocomplete with multiselect. fro that I am using http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ .. this is awesome plugins but I need something little bit different way output...

1st I need to show selected item in one separate div. currently it show on text box. 2nd I want to add option **Select All** and **Clear All**. I saw how they added search option in there. in there js file they did

`this.container.html('<a class="chosen-single chosen-default" tabindex="-1"><span>' + this.default_text + '</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" /></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div>')`

So I think if we can add one div with two button Select all and Clear all then if we can put function there for select all and clear then that will be work. also when I select all and clear all then it will effect on outside div too where I want to show all select list.

below is code

```
 <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" multiple class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="16">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option>American Black Bear</option>
        <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
        <option>Brown Bear</option>
        <option>Giant Panda</option>
        <option>Sloth Bear</option>
        <option>Sun Bear</option>
        <option>Polar Bear</option>
        <option>Spectacled Bear</option>
      </select>
```

selected list bellow

JS

```
 var config = {

  '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"75%"}
}
for (var selector in config) {
  $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Gqmhs/

Chosen document file url http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html

Answer (score 3):

Buddie, I did make this: http://jsfiddle.net/JhRL5/1/
But I am very tired and I cant finish now. But I believe that this code will help you a lot.

```
var config = {
      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"75%"}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#test").change(function(){
        var a = $("#test :selected").text();
        $("#selectedlist").html(a);
    });

    $("#s-all").click(function(){

        var a = $("#test option");

        $.each( a, function( i, val ) {
            $(val).change();
        });

        var b = $("#test option").text();
        $("#selectedlist").html(b);

    });

    $("#c-all").click(function(){

        $("#test option:selected").removeAttr("selected");

        var a = $("#test :selected").text();
        $("#selectedlist").html(a);
        $(".chosen-choices").find("li.search-choice").remove();

    });

});
```

Comment: wow.. this is awesome... @rafaelsoufraz.. i am trying myself now rest of.. i know you never finish yet..

now your code have some issue. like if i click Clear all then clear but from selection all are disable .. mean that not update, next in div where we are showing selected item there need X sybmol for each then we can delete from there,  also i wish select all button put inside selection box at first... let me try.. you also try if you have time .. i am not so good on js..

Comment: mainly i want to add/show in div as like same way to added now on textbox.. like with X. in code mode i saw the code is like that
 `<li class="search-choice"><span>Brown Bear</span><a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="3"></a></li>`

Answer (score -1):

i have made what you actually want. here it is:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/JhRL5/16/][1]
```

first of all, text box goes blank immediately after select an item from drop down.
secondly, selected item shows in a div under All Items (Deletable): 
   But here i get stuck. if i select item no 1, 3, 5 then it works fine but if i select as 1, 5, 3 it goes wrong for last one. 
actually what i need to move forward is, currently selected item name (not previously selected items).